# How set value in input field using Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

I have some `div` which is repeated many times from `ngFor`. Value which I want to loop is in the array `productCarts`. In the input field in my `div` I want set value `numberOfProduct` which is stored in my array, and when I change value in input I want to store in the `numberOfProduct` . How example `productCarts.numberOfProduct`.

```
<div *ngFor="let products of productCarts>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Number of product" [(ngModel)]="products.numberOfProduct">

</div>
```

Comment: Exactly like that.

Comment: Thanks. In some moment this is not work for me and I lose 2 hours.

Comment: What is the issue or error you are getting ?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Generally if it's a form array, its best to use the reactive form way.